# Specifically scramble a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I am making an encryption program in python. I need a way to scramble a string (could be anything, any length). I tried import random's shuffle, but it is completely random.

Is there a way to scramble/shuffle a string to a specific key?
For example if my string was "John Cena" I would enter 10 as a key (for example) and the output would be "Nojh eanC".
Then if I re-ran the program and entered the exact same string and key, it would print the same result.
If it was carried out on a different computer, it would also print the same result.

Is there a library or a way in python to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: May be use hashing? See `hashlib`

Comment: will check it out ty

Comment: Are you looking to be able to reverse the scrambling, or you just need it to be repeatable?

Comment: repeatable and able to reverse would be the best. I guessed that adding - to a number would undo?

Comment: Then hashing isn't the way to go, as it is by definition irreversible.

Comment: Also, is this just a toy encryption algorithm made for fun/demonstration, or is it supposed to be serious encryption? Because if the latter, you should be using an established library.

Comment: You could use `random.seed` every time. But `random` is not advisable for secure encryption.

Comment: @FearlessENT It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. If you want proper encryption, then there are lots of examples around. If you actually want to shuffle the characters in a string according to some kind of numerical key, then you should state that clearly. As you see, the answers are not very helpful, if you're not clear enough. Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score -1):

Use hashing. It contains several hash functions, for example, `md5` or `sha224`:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha224("Nobody inspects the spammish repetition").hexdigest()
'a4337bc45a8fc544c03f52dc550cd6e1e87021bc896588bd79e901e2'
```

See documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html).

Comment: This creates an error "TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" ?

Comment: @FearlessENT, in this case make `string=string.encode('utf-8')` before applying hashing.

Comment: Also, a Hash is by design a one way function making it just as useful as a randomized string...

Answer (score -1):

You could try coming up with some kind of scheme of your own and implement this. Or you could take a look at something like ROT13, this page can show you how.

http://eddmann.com/posts/implementing-rot13-and-rot-n-caesar-ciphers-in-python/

Comment: *"You could try coming up with some kind of scheme of your own and implement this."* Yes, but that's not very helpful, is it? If the OP wants to shuffle characters in a string, then ROT13 or the Caesar cipher won't help them.